# doughnut plot variable undefined in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

thanks in advance for you response.
I have an angular material table and I need to display some plots on displaying the expandable table. Although the plots animate, I get the following message in the console.
Cannot read property 'devices' of undefined. Any idea where the idea might be? the console.log at the end is displaying the data correctly, not undefined as expected.

```
<table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
       class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>
 
      <ng-container matColumnDef="lastSeen">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last seen </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.telemetryUtc | date: 'medium'}} </td>
      </ng-container> 

      <ng-container matColumnDef="detail">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last seen </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
                <button (click)="goToDeviceDetails(element)">detail</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container> 
      
  <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
                    <div class="example-element-detail"
                        [@detailExpand]="element == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end end">
                            <div class="telemetry">
                              <div class="cards" >
                                <div class="widget-group p-12 extraPadding" fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100" *fuseIfOnDom [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}">
                                  <!-- WIDGET 1 -->
                                  <fuse-widget [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{y:'100%'}}" class="widget" fxLayout="column"
                                              >
                                    <div class="fuse-widget-front fixWidthandHeight">
                                      <div  fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                                        <div class="h2">CPU Temperature</div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div  fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" style="height: 100%">
                                        <div class="temp" *ngIf="telemetry.cpuTemperature" class="h2">
                                          {{telemetry.cpuTemperature}}º C
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="temp" *ngIf="!telemetry.cpuTemperature" class="h2">
                                          No data
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </fuse-widget>
                                  <!-- / WIDGET 1 -->
                            
                                  <!-- WIDGET 2 -->
                                  <fuse-widget [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{y:'100%'}}" class="widget" fxLayout="column"
                                              >
                                    <div class="fuse-widget-front">
                                      <div class="pl-16 pr-8 py-16 h-52" fxLayout="row"
                                          fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                                        <div class="h2">CPU</div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="pt-8 pb-32" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                        <ngx-charts-pie-chart
                                          [scheme]="cpuPlot.scheme"
                                          [results]="cpuPlot.devices"
                                          [doughnut]="true" class="fixWidthandHeight">
                                        </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="p-16 border-top" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                                        <div *ngIf="telemetry.ramUsage" class="h4 secondary-text">{{telemetry.cpuUsage || "0"}}% is used.</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="!telemetry.ramUsage" class="h4 secondary-text">No data.</div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </fuse-widget>
                                  <!-- / WIDGET 2 -->
                            
                                  <!-- WIDGET 3 -->
                                  <fuse-widget [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{y:'100%'}}" class="widget" fxLayout="column"
                                              >
                                    <div class="fuse-widget-front">
                                      <div class="pl-16 pr-8 py-16 h-52" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                                        <div class="h2">RAM</div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="pt-8 pb-32" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                        <ngx-charts-pie-chart
                                          [scheme]="ramPlot.scheme"
                                          [results]="ramPlot.devices"
                                          [doughnut]="true" class="fixWidthandHeight">
                                        </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="p-16 border-top" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                                        <div *ngIf="telemetry.ramUsage" class="h4 secondary-text">{{telemetry.ramUsage | number:'1.0-0'}}MB of {{element.ramTotal | number:'1.0-0'}}MB used.</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="!telemetry.ramUsage" class="h4 secondary-text">No data.</div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </fuse-widget>
                                  <!-- / WIDGET 3 -->
                            
                                  <!-- WIDGET 4 -->
                                  <fuse-widget [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{y:'100%'}}" class="widget" fxLayout="column"
                                              >
                                    <div class="fuse-widget-front">
                                      <div class="pl-16 pr-8 py-16 h-52" fxLayout="row"
                                        fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                                        <div class="h2">DISK</div>
                                      </div>    
                                      <div class="pt-8 pb-32" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                        <ngx-charts-pie-chart
                                          [scheme]="diskPlot.scheme"
                                          [results]="diskPlot.devices"
                                          [doughnut]="true" class="fixWidthandHeight">
                                        </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="p-16 border-top" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                                        <div *ngIf="telemetry.diskUsage" class="h4 secondary-text">{{telemetry.diskUsage | number:'1.0-0'}}MB of {{element.diskTotal | number:'1.0-0'}}MB used.</div>
                                        <div *ngIf="!telemetry.diskUsage" class="h4 secondary-text">No data.</div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </fuse-widget>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </td>
      </ng-container>

              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"
                  class="example-element-row"
                  [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
                  (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element; getTelemetryData(element._id)">
              </tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
            </table>

            <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]=50 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 50]" showFirstLastButtons>
            </mat-paginator>
```

and my ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort, Sort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { DeviceModel } from '../device.model';
import { Subject, Subscription, fromEvent, merge, interval, Observable, of, } from 'rxjs';
import { ProvisionedService } from './provisioned.service';
import { fuseAnimations } from '@fuse/animations';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';
import {Telemetry} from '../detail/telemetry/telemetry.model'





@Component({
  selector: 'app-provisioned-list',
  templateUrl: './provisioned-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./provisioned-list.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0',  visibility: 'hidden'})),
      state('expanded', style({height: '*',  visibility: 'hidden'})),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
    fuseAnimations],
})
export class ProvisionedListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  confirmDialogRef: MatDialogRef<FuseConfirmDialogComponent>;
  DeviceErrorMessage: string;
  deviceList: DeviceModel[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['checkbox', 'online', 'deviceName', 'tags', 'actualVersion', 'status', 'runningApps', 'appVersion', 'lastSeen', 'detail'];
  deviceErrorMessage: string;
  checkboxes: {};
  private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any>;
  devices: any;
  selectedDevices: any[];
  private deviceListChange: Subscription = null;
  hasSelectedDevices: boolean;
  getDevicesInfoLoop: any;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.deviceList);
  tagsInput: string[];
  readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  visible = true;
  selectable = true;
  removable = true;

  telemetry: Telemetry;

  ramTotal: number;
  diskTotal: number;
  cpuPlot: any;
  ramPlot: any;
  diskPlot: any;
  uptimeInterval: any;
  uptimeDisplay: string;
  deviceId: string;


  constructor(private provisionedService: ProvisionedService,
    private router: Router, private detailService: DetailService,
    private storageService: StorageService, private snackMessageService: SnackMessageService,  public matDialog: MatDialog) {
    this._unsubscribeAll = new Subject();
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    this.selectedDevices = [];
    this.telemetry = {
      _id: "", 
      deviceId: "", 
      cpuTemperature: null,
      cpuUsage: null,
      diskUsage: null,
      ramUsage: null,
      storeDate: new Date(0),
      utc: new Date(0),
      upSince: new Date(0)
    }
    this.recalculatePlots(this.deviceId);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.deviceListChange.unsubscribe();
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDeviceList();
    this.getTelemetryData(this.deviceId);
    

    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    if (this.storageService.retrieveListPagination()) {
      this.paginator = JSON.parse(this.storageService.retrieveListPagination());
    }


  public goToDeviceDetails(deviceId): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/devices/detail'], { queryParams: { device: deviceId._id } });
  }



  public getTelemetryData(deviceId): void{
    this.provisionedService.getDeviceTelemetry(deviceId).then(telemetry=>{
      this.telemetry = telemetry;
      this.recalculatePlots(deviceId);
    }).catch(err=>{});
  }


  private recalculatePlots(deviceId): void{
    this.dataSource.data.forEach(element=> {
      if (!this.telemetry.cpuUsage){
        this.cpuPlot = {
          scheme : {
            domain: ["#039be5", "gainsboro"]
          },
          devices: [
            {
              "name"  : "Used",
              "value" : 0
            },
            {
              "name"  : "Available",
              "value" : 100
            }
          ]
        };
       
      } else {
        this.cpuPlot = {
          scheme : {
            domain: ["#039be5", "gainsboro"]
          },
          devices: [
            {
              "name"  : "Used",
              "value" : this.telemetry.cpuUsage
            },
            {
              "name"  : "Available",
              "value" : 100 - this.telemetry.cpuUsage
            }
          ]
        };
      }
  
      if (!this.telemetry.ramUsage || !element.ramTotal){
        this.ramPlot = {
          scheme : {
            domain: ["#039be5", "gainsboro"]
          },
          devices: [
            {
                "name"  : "Used",
                "value" : 0
            },
            {
                "name"  : "Available",
                "value" : 100
            }
          ]
        };
      } else {
        this.ramPlot = {
          scheme : {
            domain: ["#039be5", "gainsboro"]
          },
          devices: [
            {
                "name"  : "Used",
                "value" : (this.telemetry.ramUsage / element.ramTotal) * 100
            },
            {
                "name"  : "Available",
                "value" : 100 - (this.telemetry.ramUsage / element.ramTotal) * 100
            }
          ]
        };
      }
      
      if (!this.telemetry.diskUsage || !element.diskTotal) {
        this.diskPlot = {
          scheme : {
            domain: ["#039be5", "gainsboro"]
          },
          devices: [
            {
              "name"  : "Used",
              "value" : 0
            },
            {
              "name"  : "Available",
              "value" : 100
            }
          ]
        };
      } else {
        this.diskPlot = {
          scheme : {
            domain: ["#039be5", "gainsboro"]
          },
          devices: [
            {
              "name"  : "Used",
              "value" : (this.telemetry.diskUsage / element.diskTotal) * 100
            },
            {
              "name"  : "Available",
              "value" : 100 - (this.telemetry.diskUsage / element.diskTotal) * 100
            }
          ]
        };
      }
      console.log(this.cpuPlot, this.ramPlot, this.diskPlot )
    })
    }
   

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `recalculatePlots()` method is triggered asynchronously. So by the time the plots are rendered in the DOM, either of the `ramPlot`, `diskPlot` or `cpuPlot` could be undefined. Trying to access a property `devices` on them then throws the `undefined` error.

However the data is quickly fetched and the variables are defined properly. So the plot is initialized by the time the error is also shown.

To workaround it, you could use safe navigation operator `?.` in the HTML template when accessing properties. It ensures the variable is defined before trying to access it's properties.

```html
<ngx-charts-pie-chart [scheme]="cpuPlot?.scheme" [results]="cpuPlot?.devices" [doughnut]="true" class="fixWidthandHeight">
</ngx-charts-pie-chart>
...
<ngx-charts-pie-chart [scheme]="ramPlot?.scheme" [results]="ramPlot?.devices" [doughnut]="true" class="fixWidthandHeight">
</ngx-charts-pie-chart>
...
<ngx-charts-pie-chart [scheme]="diskPlot?.scheme" [results]="diskPlot?.devices" [doughnut]="true" class="fixWidthandHeight">
</ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

Notice the `?.` operator before the `devices` property.

Comment: Thanks Michael, now I'm getting the error with domain:  at new ColorHelper (swimlane-ngx-charts.js:4157) and no idea how to fix this

Comment: @novita: I'd suggest you to Google for the issue. If it stems from a library, then it's probably already recorded somewhere. If not, then you need to create a new issue here.